# How to create combination groups in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a given table as input:

| CategoryPosition | CategoryId | CategoryName | CategoryItemId | CategoryItemName | CategoryItemPosition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | Gender | 11 | Male | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | Gender | 12 | Female | 2 |
| 2 | 10 | Gender | 13 | N/A | 3 |
| 1 | 7 | Hours | 34 | 0 - 11 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | Hours | 35 | 12 - 39 | 2 |
| 1 | 7 | Hours | 36 | 40 - 79 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 | Hours | 37 | 80 - 119 | 4 |
| 1 | 7 | Hours | 38 | 120+ | 5 |
| 0 | 5 | Age | 51 | 16-18 | 1 |
| 0 | 5 | Age | 52 | 19-24 | 2 |
| 0 | 5 | Age | 53 | 25-44 | 3 |
| 0 | 5 | Age | 54 | 45-54 | 4 |
| 0 | 5 | Age | 55 | 55-59 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 | Age | 56 | 60+ | 6 |

Total number of rows : 3 (number of items from Gender ) + 5 ( number of items from Hours) + 6 (number of items from Age) = 14

What I need to produce is an output table using combinations groups of items from the 3 categories like below.

| GroupPos | CategoryPosition | CategoryId | CategoryName | CategoryItemPosition | CategoryItemId | CategoryItemName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 5 | Age | 1 | 51 | 16-18 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | Hours | 1 | 34 | 0 - 11 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | Gender | 1 | 11 | Male |
| 2 | 0 | 5 | Age | 2 | 52 | 19-24 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 | Hours | 1 | 34 | 0 - 11 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | Gender | 1 | 11 | Male |
| 3 | 0 | 5 | Age | 3 | 53 | 25-44 |
| 3 | 1 | 7 | Hours | 1 | 34 | 0 - 11 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | Gender | 1 | 11 | Male |

......

Total number of rows : 3 (number of items from Gender ) * 5 ( number of items from Hours) * 6 (number of items from Age) * 3 (number of categories) = 270

Comment: Please let the good folks here know what you've tried so far.  As it stands, your post looks suspiciously like a homework assignment!  Since you have stated this is a SQL Server question, I would suggest doing a little research on Common Table Expressions (CTEs) which you can use to sub-divide your data.  Also look up "cross join".

Comment: Don't expect to get 270 result rows. Gender, Hours, and Age *are* the three categories, so  it's 3 x 5 x 6 = 90 combinations.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner,  OP also unpivots every combination into 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You want kind of cross join plus unpivot

```
select (row_number() over(order by t1.CategoryItemPosition, t2.CategoryItemPosition, t3.CategoryItemPosition) - 1) / 3 + 1 GroupPos, t.*
from tbl t1 
join tbl t2 on t1.CategoryId = 10 and t2.CategoryId = 7 
join tbl t3 on t3.CategoryId = 5
cross apply (
 values 
   (0, t1.CategoryName, t1.CategoryId, t1.CategoryItemName, t1.CategoryItemId, t1.CategoryItemPosition),
   (1, t2.CategoryName, t2.CategoryId, t2.CategoryItemName, t2.CategoryItemId, t2.CategoryItemPosition),
   (2, t3.CategoryName, t3.CategoryId, t3.CategoryItemName, t3.CategoryItemId, t3.CategoryItemPosition)
) t(CategoryPosition, CategoryName, CategoryId, CategoryItemName, CategoryItemId, CategoryItemPosition)
order by t1.CategoryItemPosition, t2.CategoryItemPosition, t3.CategoryItemPosition
```

Answer (score 0):

select the different attributes as if dealing with different tables:

```
with g as (select categoryitemname as gender from mytable where categoryname = 'Gender')
   , h as (select categoryitemname as hours from mytable where categoryname = 'Hours')
   , a as (select categoryitemname as age from mytable where categoryname = 'Age')
select *
from g cross join h cross join a
order by g.gender, h.hours, a.age;
```

Add more columns to the subqueries, if you need them. The result look different from what you have shown as your desired result, but I think this is more or less what you are actually after.